# ¿como hago para mostrar o llamar a un componente desde otro componente?

Tags: reactjs

**Necesito que al hacer clic en mi primer componente se muestre mi segundo componente. Alguna idea de como hacerlo estoy usando Reactjs**
Necesito alguno consejos de como hacerlo o algún ejemplo en concreto

**Primer componente:**

```
import React from "react";
import  CardWhatsApp  from "../shared/CardWhatsApp";


export default function ButtonWhatsApp() {
  return (
    <div className="buttom-img">
      <img src="/images/svg/WhatsApp.svg" height="60" width="60"
               />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Segundo componente:**

```
import React from "react";

export default function CardWhatsApp() {
  return (
    <div className="dialog" >
      <div class="dialog-header">
        <div className="dialog-img">
          <img src="/images/svg/WhatsApp.svg" height="40" width="40" />
        </div>
        <div className="dialog-title">
          <h5> WhatsApp </h5>
        </div>
        <div className="dialog-close">
          <img src="/images/svg/close.svg" height="30" width="30" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dialog-body">
        <p class="dialog-text">Hola, necesitas ayuda en algo?</p>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button className="btnWhat btnWhat-send">Enviar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  ) ;
}
```

Comment: Ya lo importaste, `<CardWhatsApp />` dentro del primer componente debe funcionar

Comment: Además de lo que dice @CamiloGomez, si quieres que el segundo componente se oculte o se visualice dependiendo alguna condición, debes manejar ese estado con `useState`